# How to use SSH to access file shares: Win2012->2012 from service

Tags: windows, ssh, file-sharing, server-message-block

This relates to Win2012-R2 on both sides of the equation.

Bitvise and others have shown how to do SMB over SSH, for example here:
http://www.bitvise.com/file-sharing

However, this has the downside of only coming up when an interactive login comes up. It has the further downside that bitvise says it may not work on win2012, and they don't know how to do it/won't support it on the bitvise tool chain.

We would like to use SSH as the transport for SQL Log Shipping (with bitvise, or with another ssh tool).

How can SSH be used to allow file share access for windows services?

Constraints:

- there is no domain, for either machine. they are stand alone servers in different dc's
- the operation needs to be automatic (recreate the ssh tunnel if it goes down, etc)

Comment: May I ask why you're so fixed on SSH? Sure, you may be able to make it work, but it's a hack. Why not use IPsec? That's the perfect tool for this.

Comment: I am fine w ipsec! But have not found a straight, complete, powershell script that can be used on both sides to bring up such a connection. If such a reply were posted here, I would accept it.

Comment: Well, you're asking for a handout, which we don't do here. Take a hack at writing such a script! You'll learn a ton, and then when complete, can contribute that back via a self-answered question here. Along the way, come back here with specific powershell questions - there are several experts that answer questions regularly here.

Comment: @EEAA No handout sought! The SSH and powershell approaches must be done / documented by others. I just haven't found them yet. Just looking for pointers.